# error when launching the application in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I wrote the code, ran it. This error came out, I thought it was just an accident, and tried to launch a working project, but the error happened again. What could be the problem?

```
Install successfully finished in 10 s 468 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```